# what does "::" (double colon) operator mean in "Chunk::new" in Java?

Tags: java

I am getting [hs_err_pid fatal logs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/felog-138657.html) from a tomcat process, and inside the log it says

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 1035152 bytes for Chunk::new. Out of swap space?
#
#  Internal Error (allocation.cpp:215), pid=2060, tid=3980
#  Error: Chunk::new
#
# JRE version: 6.0_21-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (17.0-b17 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

My question isn't specifically about the OutOfMemoryError, but about how to interpret the `Chunk::new` phrase.

I see [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-May/004979.html) that apparently the double colon is an operator in Java, but I don't know for sure what it does. Would that have something to do with my situation?

Comment: that's a cpp error...

Comment: That is an error description , not a operator.

Comment: It's a native code error, not Java. This is a `c` construct, same as the dot in Java.

Comment: ahh!! That makes more sense. Well, I suppose whoever puts that as an answer will be accepted :)

Comment: @BoristheSpider C++, I think.  The first word refers to a class name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything in Java before version 8 (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8)).

What you're seeing refers to C++ code.  The first word is the class name, second is the method name.  The `::` itself is called the [Scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator).

The error you're getting is from the C++ code of the JVM itself.

Comment: And that `new` operator happens to be defined in `src/hotspot/src/share/vm/memory/allocation.ccp` line 311 from http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot/hotspot. In case there exists a single other soul who cares :).

Comment: now it means a thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8

Comment: Silly march of progress...  I've updated the answer to be pre-Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates Java has failed to acquire more memory from the operating system.

JVM you are using is developed on C++. but JVM things are vendor specific.

There is nothing to do with :: this operator.